# Calculating a trading profit rate

Tags: python, backtesting

I wanted to chek my backtester engine, so I opened a tradingview account and I ran the same test. All buy and sell numbers, prices, dates, indicator calculation, etc were exactly same, but profit calculation was different. Here is an example:

On BNB/USDT I bought @28.0750 and sold @27.5224 with commission %0.001, so I calculated -2.164% Loss in this case, but tradingview says it is -1,99%

So my basic math is like this.

```
Buy  >> 0.999/28.0750 = 0,035583259  (incl. %0.001 fee)
Sell >> 0.999*27.5224 = 27,4948776   (incl. %0.001 fee)

PLratio >> 0,035583259 * 27,4948776 = 0.978357350814 
Pct >> (0.978357350814  -1)*100 = -2.1642649186
```

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is -2.1641666 % with fees (since the buy price is 1.001*28.0750), -1.9682992 without fees. Don't know where 1.99 comes from, it seems wrong.

Comment: Found the bug. The commission should be entered as 0.1,  not 0.01 to tradingview.  But I'm not sure about. is it   0.999/28.0750   or (1/1.001*28.0750) they are not same.